# Highstock And Highcharts: How I use StockChart and pie chart on the same page

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I have a confusion about using the highstock stockchart and highcharts pie-chart on the same page. In both ways, I am getting the data using JSON. The browser cannot render the Highcharts.StockChart properly whereas it renders Highcharts.Chart type pie.

Here is the code segment that I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
$.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/reports/hits?callback=?', function(data) {
     var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        ...
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Name',
            data: data,
            tooltip: {
                yDecimals: 0
            }
        }]
     });
  })

    $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/reports/daily_hit?callback=?', function(data) {
     var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
           renderTo: 'container1',
           plotBackgroundColor: null,
           plotBorderWidth: null,
           plotShadow: false
        },
       ...
         series: [{
           type: 'pie',
           name: 'Hit',
           data: data
        }]
     });
  })
 }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of what the data looks like to test with?

Comment: Data for the highstock is sth like that:

 [[datetime1, hit1], [datetime2, hit2],.... ] looks like this, http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/goog-c.json

and data for the highcharts is sth like that: 
            [
               {
               name: 'Firefox',    
               y: 45.0,
               },
               {
               name: 'IE',    
               y: 26.8,
               },
               {
               name: 'Chrome',    
               y: 12.8,
               sliced: true,
               selected: true
               } ...
           ]

Comment: i've just founded the problem. it's not about the code, it's about the database. as i asked, i was getting the hits from database. I assumed that, there is a unique entry for every day on the db but I've just noticed, there were two entries for a single day.

So, when the data is correct, highstock stockchart and highchart pie chart can be rendered on the same page.

Comment: oh great. sometimes you just need to look at problems from different angles. funny how what you think the problem is could be furthest from the actual problem. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same problem when I tried to use Highstock chart and Angular Gauge,
And the problem was solved when I try to rearrange highstock highchart javascript library like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

or (if you don't want to use additional graphics)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highstock.js"></script>
```

I hope it can be useful

Comment: It's really baaaad idea. Highstock **contains** Highcharts, so including both isn't necessary. Just remove Highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy, put first highstock and then highchart like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

Dont's forget put the jQuery!!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This solve my problem, I hope can help you

Comment: It's really baaaad idea. Highstock **contains** Highcharts, so including both isn't necessary. Just remove Highcharts.

Comment: Ok! So i have some bug or somethig because if i delete highchart doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you have old version of Highstock/Highcharts? What kind of error do you have?

Comment: Is the last version, and don't do errors, simply don't show any. But don't worry :)